# How can I convert .SCR to .AVI

Tags: video-conversion, extract

I play a game from which I'm trying to extract videos. I extracted the '.PAK' files and the movies are in '.SCR' format. I have no idea how to convert them to '.AVI' or any playable file. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Which game? There *might* be a codec/player for the specific video format used by it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file with the program [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en), it will attempt to identify the file and see what it was encoded with.

[image]

It may be as simple as renaming the file to .avi, or you could have to download a converter, but you will at least know what format it is coming from to find a compatible converter.

Answer (score 0):

For .scr files which are actually screensaver files (which yours might not be):

Download and install the Everything search engine: http://voidtools.com/

Double-click your .scr file to run it. Open the Task Manager and terminate run32.dll (this step might not be necessary). In the Everything search tool, type in the file name of the screensaver (or part of it), without the extension. Everything may show a video file of the same name but with e.g. an .swf, .avi etc. extension. Right-click that file in the list, and click "Open containing folder."

Download and install ffmpeg into your %PATH%, or copy ffmpeg.exe into the same open folder. https://ffmpeg.org/

Open a terminal (or "DOS prompt" or "command prompt" / cmd.exe), and run these commands; replacing in.swf with the video file name you found:

```
CD <full path to the folder with the video file of the same name as the screensaver file>
ffmpeg -i in.swf -vcodec rawvideo out.avi
```

out.avi will be your result file. Or, if you hate huge lossless .avi files ;) for the second command, you could do:

```
ffmpeg -i in.swf -crf 0 out.mp4
```

The -crf 0 parameter is if you want lossless compression; if you give an .mp4 extension ffmpeg uses the default h264 codec. For compression, enter any number up to I think 50 (worst quality).

I've had some weird .swf files that turn out in reverse when converted. For those, add this switch to the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.swf -crf 0 -vf reverse out.mp4
```

Sources that helped me work this out:
http://www.answers.com/Q/How_do_convert_scr_to_avi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553448/encode-video-in-reverse

Answer (score -1):

The SCR format files are screensaver files.

You can convert the file by (From eHow.com):

**Instructions:**

**A] Converting with AVS Video Converter :**

```
1. Download AVS Video Converter to your computer. Launch the setup file and install using the default settings.

2. Once the installation is successful launch the AVS Video Converter application. Click the "Browse" button under "Input File Name" section and locate the SCR file in your drive. Then click "Open" button.

3. Click "To AVI" to convert your SCR file to AVI format. Use the "Edit Profile" section to make changes to the video size and compression. Click "Save" to save the changes made to the profile.

4. Click the "Browse" button under "Output File Name" section to set the destination directory for the converted AVI file.

5. Click "Convert Now" button to start the conversion process. Once the conversion process is finished navigate to the destination directory specified in Step 4 and verify whether the conversion is successful.
```

**B] Converting with Need4 Video Converter 7.1 :**

```
1. Download Need4 Video Converter 7.1 to your computer. Launch the setup file and install using default settings.

2. Once the installation is successful, launch the program from your desktop. Click "File" and then select "Open" from the menu. Select the desired SCR file that needs to be converted and click "Open."

3. Select "AVI---Audio Video Interleave" as the output format in the "Output file" field. Click the "Browse" button in the "Save to" field and select a name and destination for the converted file. Click "OK."

4. Click the "Convert" button to start the conversion process. Once the conversion is finished navigate to the destination directory specified in Step 4 and verify whether the conversion is successful.
```

**C] Converting with Any Video Converter :**

```
1. Download Any Video Converter freeware to your computer. Install using default settings.

2. Launch the Any Video Converter from the desktop and click the "Add Video" button. Select the desired SCR file that needs to be converted and click "Add" button.

3. Select "AVI (*.avi)" from the "Profile" menu to set the target format to AVI. Click the "Output Folder" button and select a target destination for the converted AVI file. Click "OK."

4. Click "Encode" to start the conversion process. Once the conversion is finished navigate to the destination and verify whether the conversion is successful.
```

Comment: Any extension is just a random set of letters. I am not so sure a game would use screen savers as the video format...

Comment: I agree. But as Donavon has given very little information (Not even the name of the game), I am unable to help him further.

Comment: I agree with @AthomSfere, it's highly unlikely these SCRs are screensavers. Also, I doubt AVS Video Converter or any of the other programs can convert any conventional screensaver (which are programs) to AVI. Screensavers aren't videos, although some do play videos of course.

Comment: Again, Donavon has not given enough information about what exactly he is trying to do. So that is all I could do.